# Enabling S3 bucket key via terraform

Tags: amazon-s3, terraform-provider-aws, amazon-kms

I recently came across this article about [S3 bucket key](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/bucket-key.html) and would like to implement this via terraform for new buckets.
The article shows how to enable this via the console and cloudformation but I have not been able to find any info yet online about how to do this via terraform. the [aws_s3_bucket_server_side_encryption_configuration](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/4.8.0/docs/resources/s3_bucket_server_side_encryption_configuration) page on terraform registry website doesn't have any information regarding this either.

Any help around this would be greatly appreciated

Thanks.

Comment: You are viewing and old documentation / old provider version, see https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/s3_bucket_server_side_encryption_configuration instead. And even on the version you link there is a `bucket_key_enabled` flag.

Comment: I need to get my eyes checked, and my sanity. Thanks @luk2302

Comment: @boringDeveloper seems like I have to upgrade my glasses too ! ':D